Random Lego Bags year 2011
Found these bags in a bin but don’t know what set it belongs to. 2011. Big wheels. Red, dark green. And browns


This question is similar to: How can I identify a set based on one or more original sealed bags?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi Sharon and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please take a look at the linked question and let us know if you need assistance following the steps described there, so that we can update the process. Play well!

That'd be set 70315 "Clay's Rumble Blade".

Based on 2x2 rounded inverted tile (part 2654) in trans-neon orange, and 4x4 rounded plate (part 60474) in blue.
